# Backquote no longer works within <sup>, whereas <code> does

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

Some time [ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161196/772868) this worked. Now backquotes are just displayed as backquotes as in:

<sup>Fine print with `backquoted code` and `using markup code`</sup>

Here on MSO it works... but as @Yatin remarks, it is sensitive to line breaks

as in this case,
`backquoted code`

does not work even on MSO

Comment: Very interesting. Having `<sup>` and `</sup>` in different lines causes this but having them in the same line doesn't. [See this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361858/598066). I don't think it works on MSO either. Try it...

Comment: Looks similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357552/commonmark-regression-image-embed-exclamation-sign-syntax-broken-after-p-tag